# RSelenium can't open Firefox browser

Tags: web-scraping, firefox, rselenium

I was trying to scrape an Amazon page using RSelenium in R.

So in a first instance I decided to initilize Rselenium using this lines of code

```
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
library(netstat)
library(httr)
library(rvest)
library(XML)
library(wdman)

Sys.setLanguage(lang="en")
port <- netstat::free_port()
Driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox", version="latest", port = port)
```

But, when i ran that code, the R console displayed this

```
checking Selenium Server versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking chromedriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking geckodriver versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
checking phantomjs versions:
BEGIN: PREDOWNLOAD
BEGIN: DOWNLOAD
BEGIN: POSTDOWNLOAD
[1] "Connecting to remote server"
Could not open firefox browser.
Client error message:
Undefined error in httr call. httr output: Failed to connect to localhost port 14415 after 2241 ms: Connection refused
Check server log for further details.
Warning message:
In rsDriver(browser = "firefox", version = "latest", verbose = T) :
  Could not determine server status.
```

By the way I tried to run the code with anti-virus and Defender Firewall disabled, but it didn't work

What may be the issue?

May the error be related to the incompatibility of the versions of R, Firefox and Java installed on my computer?

FYI, on my laptop are present:

R interpreter with version 4.3.0

Firefox browser with version 113.0.2 64 bit

Java build 1.8.0_371-b11 64 bit

RStudio 2023.03.0+386 "Cherry Blossom" Release (3c53477afb13ab959aeb5b34df1f10c237b256c3, 2023-03-09) for Windows
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) RStudio/2023.03.0+386 Chrome/108.0.5359.179 Electron/22.0.3 Safari/537.36

R version 4.3.0 64 bit

RSelenium package 1.7.9